# exception in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have following procedure:

```
procedure mayFailProc() as
begin
    insert into t1 (id, val) values (1, '123');
    insert into t1 (id, val) values (2, '123');
    insert into t1 (id, val) values (3, '123'); //fails, i.e. due to pk uniqueness error
end;
```

this exception thrown in `mayFailProc` is a normal thing and it is handled by its caller. So the transaction is not rolled back and execution continues as if there was no exception in `mayFailProc`. I wonder what will happen to first two successfully executed inserts? Will they be retained or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here for Oracle's explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7105).  You can jump to the How Oracle Does Implicit Rollbacks section to start.

> Before executing an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, Oracle marks
>   an implicit savepoint (unavailable to you). If the statement fails,
>   Oracle rolls back to the savepoint. Usually, just the failed SQL
>   statement is rolled back, not the whole transaction. If the statement
>   raises an unhandled exception, the host environment determines what is
>   rolled back.

More:

> You should explicitly commit or roll back every transaction. Whether
>   you issue the commit or rollback in your PL/SQL program or from a
>   client program depends on the application logic. If you do not commit
>   or roll back a transaction explicitly, the client environment
>   determines its final state.
>
> For example, in the SQL*Plus environment, if your PL/SQL block does
>   not include a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement, the final state of your
>   transaction depends on what you do after running the block. If you
>   execute a data definition, data control, or COMMIT statement or if you
>   issue the EXIT, DISCONNECT, or QUIT command, Oracle commits the
>   transaction. If you execute a ROLLBACK statement or abort the SQL*Plus
>   session, Oracle rolls back the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Just done a quick test... the rows in my test were not retained when the third insert caused a "unique constraint ... violated" error